# Finding numbers with unique digits in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have to write a program that finds every number (except 0) which can be factored by numbers from 2-9.
For example first such a number would be number 2520 as it can be divided by every single number from 2 to 9.
It also has to be a number that contains only 1 type of digit of its own (no multiple digits in a number). So for example 2520 will not meet this requirement since there are two same digits (2). The example of a number that meets both requirements is number 7560. That is the point I don't how to do it. I was thinking about converting value in an array to string, and then putting this string in another array so every digit would be represented by one array entry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, x, flag, y = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double z = pow(10, n) - 1;
    int array[(int)z];

    for (i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
        flag = 0;
        array[i] = i;
        if (i > 0) {
            for (x = 2; x <= 9; x++) {
                if (array[i] % x != 0) {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }

            if (flag == 0) {
                y = 1;
                printf("%d\n", array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (y == 0) {
        printf("not exist");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"It also has to be a number that contains only 1 unique digit. So for example 2520 will not meet this requirement since there are two same digits (2)."* - This is a contradiction. According to the first sentence, it would fail because 2520 contains two (not only one) unique digit, 5 and 0.

Comment: *"I was thinking about converting value in an array to string, and then putting this string in another array so every digit would be represented by one array entry."* - Well, try. It is a possible way to solve it, so try.

Comment: `n = 7560; z = pow(10, n);` That doesn't sound right, for example `pow(10, 7560);` You have to check the math.

Comment: Use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) to transform the number into a string and then count the digits. The whole program should not exceed 30 lines, blank lines included.

Comment: @PatrykBesler: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a base:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char snumber[20];
  int number = 11235;

  printf("Number = %d\n\n", number);

  sprintf(snumber, "%d", number);    
  int histogram[10] = { 0 };    
  int len = strlen(snumber);

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    histogram[snumber[i] - '0']++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if (histogram[i] != 0)
      printf("%d occurs %d times\n", i, histogram[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Number = 11235

1 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 1 times
3 occurs 1 times
5 occurs 1 times
```

Comment: Note that this will work on *any* encoding: the C++ and C standards insists that 0 to 9 are in a consecutive block, so `snumber[i] - '0'` is the idiomatic way of extracting a numerical value from a character. Therefore, have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba the question is tagged C, not C++, does the C standard say the same? (I suppose so).

Comment: Yes͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Answer (score 1):

That code is a mess. Let's bin it.

> Theorem: Any number that divides all numbers in the range 2 to 9 is a
>   multiple of 2520.

Therefore your algorithm takes the form

```
for (long i = 2520; i <= 9876543210 /*Beyond this there must be a duplicate*/; i += 2520){
    // ToDo - reject if `i` contains one or more of the same digit.
}
```

For the `ToDo` part, see [How to write a code to detect duplicate digits of any given number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983097/how-to-write-a-code-to-detect-duplicate-digits-of-any-given-number-in-c). Granted, it's C++, but the accepted answer ports verbatim.

Comment: Given the other requirement, it could be `for (uint64_t i = 2520; i <= 9876543210; ...`.

Comment: @Bob__: Showoff ;-) But I've pinched that. Couldn't resist. I'll upvote an answer of yours for good karma.

Comment: @Bathsheba FYI the question you linked was removed from SO.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, your problem is that you need to identify whether a number is consisted of multiple digits.
Following your proposed approach, to convert the number into a string and use an array to represent digits, i can suggest the following solution for a function that implements it. The main function is used to test the has_repeated_digits function. It just shows a way to do it. 
You can alter it and use it in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS_IN_NUM  20

//returns 1 when there are repeated digits, 0 otherwise
int has_repeated_digits(int num){

  // in array, array[0] represents how many times the '0' is found
  // array[1], how many times '1' is found etc...
  int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  char num_string[MAX_DIGITS_IN_NUM];

  //converts the number to string and stores it in num_string
  sprintf(num_string, "%d", num);

  int i = 0;
  while (num_string[i] != '\0'){

    //if a digit is found more than one time, return 1.
    if (++array[num_string[i] - '0'] >= 2){
        return 1;   //found repeated digit
    }
    i++;
   }

 return 0;  //no repeated digits found
}


// test tha function

int main()
{
  int x=0;
  while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF){
    if (has_repeated_digits(x))
        printf("repeated digits found!\n");
    else
        printf("no repeated digits\n");
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your problem from these remarks:

- the least common multiple of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 is 2520.
- numbers larger than 9876543210 must have at least twice the same digit in their base 10 representation.
- checking for duplicate digits can be done by counting the remainders of successive divisions by 10.

A simple approach is therefore to enumerate multiples of 2520 up to 9876543210 and select the numbers that have no duplicate digits.

Type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be large enough to represent all values to enumerate, but neither `int` nor `long` are.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long i, n;
    for (n = 2520; n <= 9876543210; n += 2520) {
        int digits[10] = { 0 };
        for (i = n; i != 0; i /= 10) {
            if (digits[i % 10]++)
                break;
        }
        if (i == 0)
            printf("%llu\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program produces **13818** numbers in 0.076 seconds. The first one is **7560** and the last one is **9876351240**.

The number **0** technically does match your constraints: it is evenly divisible by all non zero integers and it has no duplicate digits. But you excluded it explicitly.